# Calculo de longitud de caracteres condiciones en javascript

Tags: javascript

Hola buenas tardes tengo este problema en javascript:

Tengo un avance en el cual este javascript te dice a través de un cuadro de texto, cuántos caracteres y palabras escribes y lo manda en una pantalla, pero requiero que esto se haga con un menu, donde el usuario escriba un mensaje y tenga las siguientes condiciones:

Si el mensaje o cadena escrito en el cuadro de texto, es menor a 10 caracteres y cualquier palabra(s) que imprima en pantalla es cadena corta.

Si el mensaje o cadena escrito en el cuadro de texto, es mayor a 10 caracteres y menor a 20 caracteres, cualquier palabra(s) que imprima en pantalla es cadena media.

Si el mensaje o cadena escrito en el cuadro de texto, es mayor a 20 caracteres y cualquier palabra(s) que imprima en pantalla es cadena larga.

Pero no se como poner estas condiciones con lo que llevo, me ayudan por favor, mil gracias.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Caracteres</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style type="text/css">
    body    {
background-color:#DBDFDB; 
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<font color="#030303" face="georgia" size="5"> 
<center>
    <TABLE BORDER=3 width="1000" height="50">
    <TR><TD>
        <font face="georgia" size="30">
    <MARQUEE SCROLLAMOUNT=10 BEHAVIOR="alternate"><b>Programa para calcular caracteres</b></MARQUEE>
    </font>
    </TD></TR>
    </TABLE>
<p>Menu: </p>
<p>1 a 10 Es una cadena corta</p>
<p>10 a 20 Es una cadena media</p>
<p>Mayores a 20 Es una cadena larga</p>

<script type="text/javascript">
function wordCount() {
  textoArea = document.getElementById("area").value;
  numeroCaracteres = textoArea.length;
  inicioBlanco = /^ /
  finBlanco = / $/  
  variosBlancos = /[ ]+/g 
  textoArea = textoArea.replace(inicioBlanco,"");
  textoArea = textoArea.replace(finBlanco,"");
  textoArea = textoArea.replace(variosBlancos," ");  
  textoAreaDividido = textoArea.split(" ");
  numeroPalabras = textoAreaDividido.length;
  tC = (numeroCaracteres==1)?" carácter":" caracteres";
  tP = (numeroPalabras==1)?" palabra":" palabras";
  alert (numeroCaracteres + tC +"\n" + numeroPalabras + tP);
 }
</script>

<FORM ID="formulario" ACTION="#">
<TEXTAREA ID="area" COLS=20 ROWS=10>
Texto dentro del área de texto </TEXTAREA><BR>
<INPUT TYPE="button" VALUE="Contar las palabras" onClick="wordCount();">
</FORM>

</center>
</font>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Edita la pregunta y añade el código, no lo añadas como comentarios

Answer (score 1):

Bueno la solución que tengo esta en este código, trata de hacer esto

Contar los caracteres que estas metiendo en cada input recuperar el valor y pasarlo por una condición y definir el mensaje como te lo dejo en el ejemplo funcionable

```js
function contadorcaracteres(){
    
           var numeroCaracteres = 0;
           var textoArea = $('#nombre').val();
           numeroCaracteres = textoArea.length;
              
              if(numeroCaracteres == 10){
                $('#open').text('Son 10 caracteres');
                otroinput();
              }
}
function contadorcaracteres1(){
    
           var numeroCaracteres1 = 0;
           var textoArea1 = $('#nombre1').val();
           numeroCaracteres1 = textoArea1.length;
              
              if(numeroCaracteres1 == 20){
                $('#open').text('Son 20 caracteres');
                otroinput2();
              }
}
function contadorcaracteres2(){
    
           var numeroCaracteres2 = 0;
           var textoArea2 = $('#nombre2').val();
           numeroCaracteres2 = textoArea2.length;
              
              if(numeroCaracteres2 == 30){
                $('#open').text('Son 30 caracteres');
                otroinput3();
              }
}
function otroinput(){
  $('#primerinput1').show(600);

}


function otroinput2(){
  $('#primerinput2').show(600);

}

function otroinput3(){
  $('#primerinput3').show(600)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <label>Numero de caracteres que no sean mas de 10</label>
  <input type='text' name='nombre' id='nombre' onkeypress = 'contadorcaracteres()'>


<div style='display:none;' id='primerinput1'>
  <label>Numero de caracteres que sean mas de 10 y menos de 20</label>
  <input type='text' name='nombre1' id='nombre1' onkeypress = 'contadorcaracteres1()'>
</div>
<div style='display:none;' id='primerinput2'>
  <label>Numero de caracteres que sean mas de 20 y menos de 30</label>
  <input type='text' name='nombre' id='nombre2' onkeypress = 'contadorcaracteres2()'>
</div>
<div style='display:none;' id='primerinput3'>Finalizado el test de los input</div>
<div id='open'></div>
```

Recuerda instalar las librerías necesarios para que jquery pueda funcionar junto con javascript

e modificado el codigo para que veas que funcionamiento tiene cuando obligas a las personas escribir,

- Escribe los primero 10 caracteres
  si no los escribes no te dejara ver los demás impute

Comment: ok veo que funciona, pero por ejemplo como le podria hacer para que al usuario le solicite escribir y de ahi cuando termine, que aplique las condiciones que solicita el programa?

Comment: Hola, Puedes validar los input que sean obligatorios.

Comment: La otra que se me ocurre seria a travez de un prompt que el usuario escriba lo que sea y que cuando de en aceptar como resultado muestre depende las condiciones que puse pero no se como desarrollarlas =(

Comment: Me ayudan por favor

Comment: Ok, ahora edito mi ejemplo para quesea obligatorio la escritura.

Comment: Listo hermano, Agregue las validaciones que obliga al cliente escribir los primeros 10 caracteres si quiere seguir al siguiente input

Comment: si tienes razon ya realice pruebas y listo si funciona, muchisimas gracias ing!! por su apoyo para esa actividad, estamos en contacto (Y)